Execute .sh remotely
I have a remote server with .sh file which I must trigger in order to restart locally running node services.
When I run the following,
ssh -i ~/key.pem user@1123.123.123.123
cd /home/user
./services.sh

I'm getting this console output,
Killing all nodes
node: no process found
Starting auth service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
Starting data service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
Starting events service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
Starting logs service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
Starting UI service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
Starting API Gatwaay service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
All services started

However, when I'm running this command,
ssh -tt user@1123.123.123.123 -p 22 /home/user/services.sh

The output I'm getting is this,
Killing all nodes
Starting auth service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'npm': No such file or directory
Starting data service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'npm': No such file or directory
Starting events service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'npm': No such file or directory
Starting logs service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'npm': No such file or directory
Starting UI service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'npm': No such file or directory
Starting API Gatwaay service...
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'npm': No such file or directory
All services started

And my nodes are not restarted so I have to manually connect to the server and execute the script like I do in my first example.
This is my script:
#!/bin/bash

# Include profile
. /etc/profile

echo "Killing all nodes"
killall node

echo "Starting auth service..."
cd /home/user/auth
nohup npm run start:prod &
sleep 5

echo "Starting data service..."
cd /home/user/data
nohup npm run start:prod &
sleep 5

echo "Starting events service..."
cd /home/user/event
nohup npm run start:prod &
sleep 5

echo "Starting logs service..."
cd /home/user/log
nohup npm run start:prod &
sleep 5

echo "Starting UI service..."
cd /home/user/ui
nohup npm run start:server &
sleep 5

echo "Starting API Gatwaay service..."
cd /home/user/api
nohup npm run start:prod &
sleep 5

echo "All services started"

How can achieve the same result with a single line command?

In your first example, ssh starts an interactive shell; in your second example, a non-interactive shell is used to execute your script immediately. Perhaps it's a local .bashrc file that adds npm to your PATH, rather than /etc/profile? (In any case, there shouldn't be any reason for a script to source /etc/profile explicitly.)

Yeah but what does that mean? How can I run the script without connecting to the server?

I can see additional path in my PATH when I echo it while being connected to the server, which is /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin, but I don't understand where ubuntu user is loading it from while connected to the server and why it's not loaded in a non-interactive way.

Double-checking the man page, I'll correctly myself slightly. If you give ssh a command argument (or multiple arguments that ssh combines into a single string), it executes that command using a non-interactive shell, which doesn't source any configuration files before hand. If you don't give it a command, it executes a login shell, which sources .bash_profile on startup. You can execute an explicit login shell with ssh ... bash -l /home/user/services.sh

You mean this ssh -tt user@1123.123.123.123 -p 22 bash -l /home/user/services.sh?

I would recommend ssh ... 'bash -l /home/user/services.sh', but yes, that should ensure .bash_profile is sourced before executing services.sh.

Hm, didn't make any difference. My lead says it's likely to do with the tty, but I don't understand what it means.

After all, I have made it working as @chepner suggested.
My command look like this now
ssh user@123.123.123.123 -p 22 'bash -l /home/user/services.sh'

And I've added the following line to my ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/:$PATH"

